# h:panelgroup body still executed when rendered attribut evaluate to false

Tags: jsf

I don't understand why the body of h:panelGroup still execute even when `rendered="false"`

`<h:panelGroup rendered="false" layout="block"> this code is still execute </h:panelGroup>`

Am using jsf 2.2.13 and tomcat 7.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774516/although-rendered-false-content-of-a-hdatatable-is-always-evaluated ? jsf-2.2.13 being Mojarra or MyFaces for you? Tried other versions?

Comment: Can you try using a an `id` on the panelGroup, or a `style="... "` (e.g. color:red). Could be the 'rendered' is ignored if not one of these is present. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974729/panelgroup-without-style-or-styleclass-is-not-rendered-unless-id-is-given (but it does not explicitly state that... Might be a bug

Comment: @Kukeltje being Mojarra 2.2.13 and i tried with an `id` on the panelGroup, still the same behavior.

Comment: What's in the panelGroup? I can't get it to replicate using 2.2.12 using a simple outputText as the child.